# I Get 403 CSRF Mismatch when I'm trying to send the "post" request to SailsJS server

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, sails.js, csrf

I have a sailsJS server. I try to send post request from client on another domain.

I send _csrf from /csrfToken, but I'm getting 403 csrf mismatch again and again

The client code looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://myserverdomain.ru/csrfToken'
                  success: (response) ->
                      $.ajax({
                          url: 'http://myserverdomain.ru/session/create'
                          type: "POST"
                          crossDomain: true
                          xhrFields: {
                              withCredentials: true
                          }
                          data: {_csrf: response._csrf, email: 'mail@mail', password: 'password'}
                          error: () ->
                              console.log 'error'
                          success: ( resp ) ->
                              console.log resp
                      })
            })
```

configs of the server:

```
module.exports.csrf = {
    grantTokenViaAjax: true,
    origin: 'http://myclientdomain.ru'
};


module.exports.cors = {

  allRoutes: true,

  origin: 'http://myclientdomain.ru',

  credentials: true,

  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',

  headers: 'content-type'
```

response looks like this:

```
CSRF mismatch
```

general:

```
Remote Address:ip.ip.ip.1:1010
Request URL:http://myserverdomain.ru/session/create
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

requested headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Content-Length:95
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:sails.sid=s%3A_HBoGJvI9N_-kH3Bj2LBrIrayWAb_k4z.N9P%2F%2Bt%2FDWCFAuK1MvBNjyYO1ntmp5m8a5Te0IM%2Ftn7s; BCSI-CS-c82c2a7dcc10e8b5=2
Host:myserverdomain.ru
Origin:http://myserverdomain.ru
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://myserverdomain.ru/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
```

form data:

```
_csrf:ljGDMpSr-_O1ktMJ-zHEJfWaKPygXwNSSjcU
email:mail@mail
password:password
```

Help me, please!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with SailsJs, but after spending few minutes on their Documentation, what you are doing seems correct, but I would try couple of things

1. Try setting _csrf in the header.
2. Change the `origin` in the `module.exports.csrf` to *

   `module.exports.csrf = {
      grantTokenViaAjax: true,
      origin: '*'
   }`

Comment: I would not recommend this approach. setting a CSRF origin to wildcard would result in a rouge site being able to retrieve and post CSRF token. Defeating the purpose of CSRF.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send it in the header

Add X-CSRF-Token:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://myserverdomain.ru/csrfToken'
success: (response) ->
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://myserverdomain.ru/session/create'
      type: "POST"
      crossDomain: true
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '_PUT_YOUR_CSRF_HERE_');
      }
      xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
      }
      data: {_csrf: response._csrf, email: 'mail@mail', password: 'password'}
      error: () ->
          console.log 'error'
      success: ( resp ) ->
          console.log resp
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't help. Response: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserverdomain.ru/session/create. Request header field X-CSRF-Token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Should I change the "heders" in module.exports.cors?

Comment: I've added a header `headers: 'content-type,X-CSRF-Token'` but the server responds with 403 CSRF mismatch again

Comment: Strange, by the way I don't use grantTokenViaAjax and origin in csrf.js, also cors.js is the default. Could you please try it with default csrf.js and cors.js? Comment everything in cors.js. In csrf.js I only have module.exports.csrf = true;. Try it just for a quick test. And make sure you restart the application. I don't even have the X-CSRF-Token in the headers. I also don't use the /csrfToken call. I use EJS template so when I have to use _csrf I do like: data: {_csrf: <%= _csrf %>, email: 'mail@mail', password: 'password'}, so the _csrf will included in the rendered html.

Comment: The code "<%= _csrf %>" will not work in cross domain ajax =) Only /csrfToken can return csrf for another domain which allowed in csrf config.

Comment: I can see that you are sending a cookie in your request header. Is that cookie coming from the request to /csrfToken? If not, you could try to get the set-cookie header form the /csrfToken response and send it back with the /session/create request as Cookie header. You can get the set-cookie header with xhr.getResponseHeader("set-cookie"), and send back with xhr.setRequestHeader('Cookie', '_PUT_YOUR_COOKIE_FROM_RESPONSE_HERE_');

Comment: This is the cookie that I got from /csrfToken... Maybe just turn off csrf option?
I'm so tired to look for a problem. 
Why damn it does not work?

Comment: @derzunov did you ever solve this? I've got exactly the same issue.

Comment: sorry, but no. I just switched off the csrf-token functionality

Answer (score 0):

In the config/crfs.js, add these lines and your route:

```
module.exports.csrf = {
  grantTokenViaAjax: true
  , routesDisabled: '*Route URLs*',
  'origin': '*'
}
```